# Validar compo input file array con PHP no funciona

Tags: php

Estoy intentando validar un campo `input` de tipo `file` con un `if` pero no funciona. Ya probé de todas las formas y no se dónde está el error. El campo es un `array`.

Les dejo una porción del código.

```
<form action="editar-tarjetas-accion.php" class="needs-validation" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<input type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" id="fotofrente" class="form-control-file" name="fotofrente[]" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Editar dni</button>
</form>
```

Código PHP

```
$fotofrente = $_FILES["fotofrente"];

if ($_FILES['fotofrente']['name'] != null) {
  echo "El campo tiene datos";
}else{
  echo "No hay datos";
}
```

No sé si es porque es un `array` el campo.

Comment: Siempre puedes revisar como te llegan los datos en `php` usando las funciones `var_dump()` o `print_r()` y pasando dentro el elemento que necesites verificar. Por ejemplo, con `$_FILES` quedaría así: `print_r($_FILES)`, o con `$_POST` así: `var_dump($_POST)`. Con el resultado que obtienes, ya sabrás que manejo darle a los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable [**`$_FILES`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php) te devuelve un array asociativo, y deberías ingresar a la posición de ese array con `[0]`, tu validación quedaría así:

```
$fotofrente = $_FILES["fotofrente"];

if ($fotofrente['name'][0] != null) {
echo "El campo tiene datos";
}else{
echo "No hay datos";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste, sabes como renegué con eso. Mil gracias